# How can I set the form action through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form whose action should be set dynamically through JavaScript. How do I do it?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action() { // Inside script tags
        return form_action;
    }
</script>

<form action=get_action()>
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You cannot invoke JavaScript functions in standard HTML attributes other than `onXXX`. Just assign it during window onload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.myform.action = get_action();
    }

    function get_action() {
        return form_action;
    }
</script>

<form name="myform">
    ...
</form>
```

You see that I've given the form a `name`, so that it's easily accessible in `document`.

Alternatively, you can also do it during `submit` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action(form) {
        form.action = form_action;
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="get_action(this);">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Although, depending on markup this may not validate, the 'name' attribute is not a valid attribute in XML, its better to use an ID and use the getElementById

Comment: @Rabbott: It's HTML, not XML. XHTML is only interesting for server-side HTML-autogenerators like componentbased MVC frameworks.

Answer (score 79):

Plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('form_id').action; //Will retrieve it

document.getElementById('form_id').action = "script.php"; //Will set it
```

Using jQuery...

```
$("#form_id").attr("action"); //Will retrieve it

$("#form_id").attr("action", "/script.php"); //Will set it
```

Comment: Hi, I think for plain JavaScript line 2: document.getElementById('form_id').action = "script.php" will retrieve it  <-- This will SET it.

Comment: It was a nice option, I used the Plain Javascript Option. I worked in the desktop view. But not getting that worked with mobile browsers

Answer (score 9):

Very easy solution with jQuery:

```
$('#myFormId').attr('action', 'myNewActionTarget.html');
```

Your form:

```
<form action=get_action() id="myFormId">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, when we want this, we want to change the action depending on which submit button we press.

Here you do not need even assign `name` or `id` to the form. Just use the `form` property of the clicked element:

```
<form action = "/default/page" >
    <input type=submit onclick='this.form.action="/this/page";' value="Save">
    <input type=submit onclick='this.form.action="/that/page";' value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the action URL of a form:

```
 <form id="myForm" action="">

     <button onclick="changeAction()">Try it</button>

 </form>

 <script>
     function changeAction() {

         document.getElementById("myForm").action = "url/action_page.php";
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.forms[0].action="http://..."
```

...assuming it is the first form on the page.

Comment: this might work, but i am still trying to make it work by getting the action string from a function. is there no way to do it like that?

Comment: You can write it in an `onsubmit` event handler to make sure it always gets just just before submission. However, in general trying to change a form action from script is a code smell; unless you don't control the server side, it's usually better to make the form accept two+ different submission modes.

Answer (score 2):

Do as Rabbott says, or if you refuse jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_action() { // inside script tags
  return form_action;
}
</script>

<form action="" onsubmit="this.action=get_action();">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setting form action after selection of option using JavaScript

```
<script>
    function onSelectedOption(sel) {
        if ((sel.selectedIndex) == 0) {
            document.getElementById("edit").action =
            "http://www.example.co.uk/index.php";
            document.getElementById("edit").submit();
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("edit").action =
            "http://www.example.co.uk/different.php";
            document.getElementById("edit").submit();
        }
    }
</script>

<form name="edit" id="edit" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{ID}" />
</form>

<select name="option" id="option" onchange="onSelectedOption(this);">
    <option name="contactBuyer">Edit item</option>
    <option name="relist">End listing</option>
</select>
```