# create a link using input and button

Tags: html, forms, popup

I want to create a form like popup that has a input and a button. When i type in an input Ex.: "good" and click on button it go to the url  "good.mydomain.com"

i did this but it doest work

```
<html>
    <form action="firstname.mydomain.com">
    Go to URL:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">.mydomain.com
    <br>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
    </p>
    </form> 
</html>
```

Comment: Try the suggestion in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-to-set-form-action-through-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this with jQuery.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="goTo" name="firstname">.mydomain.com
<input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Go">
```

Then the jQuery:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    var goTo = $("#goTo").val();
    window.location.href = 'http://'+goTo+'.mydomain.com/';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How can i do that in wordpress

Answer (score -1):

please try below code using javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Submit</title>
    <script>
        function Submit() {
            var url = "http://www." + document.getElementById("firstname").value + ".mydomain.com";
            window.location.assign(url);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Go to URL:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="">.mydomain.com
    <br>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="go" onclick="Submit()">
    </p>


</body>
</html>​​
```

Comment: i guess it is ok, but at the end a see this characters "  â€‹â€‹  ", what its?

Comment: I don't see these special characters. From where it came?

Comment: I guess it may be because of copy paste of code..  I don't see that in my file.

Comment: Yes it great solutions. :(   i  cant used in a wordpress page.  i want to put a button and when some one click on that button it popup the form.

Comment: i could put the form in a post, but the button go doesnt go to the link

Comment: Hi Imran Saddapalli i have a ex.: what a want. http://www.vendhq.com/ in this page when you click on sing in, apear a popup with the input and button. Can you see, please?

Comment: i could create the popup, but when i click on go botton it open in the same popup, i would like that open in the source page.