# how can change form action to text input?

Tags: javascript, forms, action

I want to change my form destination based on an input value.
How can I do this?

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="x.php" onSubmit="">
  <input type="url" id="address" value="google.com">
  <input type="submit" id="go" value="Go">
</form>
```

Example: When I set `http://google.com` as address value, so send this form to google.com.

Comment: Have you tried setting the forms `action` attribute during `onsubmit`?

Comment: I know that must be changed through submit. But do not know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use
"[How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)"
&
"[How can I set the form action through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-can-i-set-the-form-action-through-javascript)" to write my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_action(form) {
        form.action = 'http://'+document.getElementById("address").value;
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="get_action(this);">
  <input type="text" id="address" value="google.com">
  <input type="submit" id="go" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#address").blur(function () {
                    var form = document.getElementById('form');
                        form.action = $("#address").val();
                });
            });
</script>

<form id="form" method="POST" action="x.php" onSubmit="">
  <input type="text" id="address" value="google.com">
  <input type="submit" id="go" value="Go">
</form>
```

Comment: Not Work :( Can you type full html(form,js and other)?

Comment: @Mike amin have already add javascript tag so i suggest above solution.

Comment: @amin i have updated my answer. if you want to redirect to google.com use in input text "http://google.com"

Comment: @PrashantValanda jQuery is a Javascript library. Running Javascript does not imply you are using jQuery.