# How to add value of variable at the end of URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `counter` button which increases the number when clicked.
Also I have an URL like `http://localhost:5000/x/`.
What I want is:
Printing the `counter` value at the end of the URL.
For example:
If counter=3,
 I want to go `http://localhost:5000/x/3`;
 
My button type is `submit` and it increases the value of counter and goes the page`http://localhost:5000/x/counter`. However, I got 404 Error because the data is on the `http://localhost:5000/x/3`. Here is the code.

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/x/counter">

<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>
```

Thanks.Additional I don't use any framework and I want to handle it just by using JavaScript.
EDIT:
Thanks for your answers. I solved it by using `window.location.href` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set form action through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-to-set-form-action-through-javascript)

Comment: You could have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters

Comment: which server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve counter using url of page

```
var counter = location.href.substring(location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
counter = parseInt(counter);
counter += 1;
```

Set myform action using counter

```
document.myform.action = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/'))+counter;
```

Name your form

```
<form name='myform'>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.