# HTML Form: How to redirect a submit button based on dropdown selection

Tags: html

Apologies for the basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer for this project. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I have an HTML form that asks a range of questions to help qualify users, but I need unqualified visitors to be redirected to a different page upon submission. Can someone please help me with this code?

Here's the qualifying dropdown:
"How Much Do You Have To Spend On A Marketing Consultant (Per Month):"

- Max. $500 (this is the only selection that is to redirect the user to the unsuccessful page https://salespeach.com.au/application-unsuccessful)

The remainder of the options are fine to continue to the qualifying page which is https://salespeach.com.au/application-successful)

Here's the code for the Form:

```html
<div class="dmform default u_1293529059" preserve_css="true" dmle_widget="dudaContactUsRespId" data-element-type="dContactUsRespId" captcha="true" data-captcha-position="bottomleft" id="1293529059">
 <h3 class="dmform-title dmwidget-title" id="1662432205" hide="true">
  Application Form
 </h3>
 <div class="dmform-wrapper" preserve_css="true" id="1686894353">
  <form method="post" class="dmRespDesignRow" locale="ENGLISH" id="1629140815">
   <div class="dmforminput required  small-12 medium-4 large-4  dmRespDesignCol" id="1734735319">
    <label for="dmform-0" id="1827123630">
     Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="" name="dmform-0" id="1823254201"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-0" value="Name" id="1559939654"/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput required  small-12 medium-4 large-4  dmRespDesignCol" id="1398791148">
    <label for="dmform-1" id="1167704783">
     Email:
    </label>
    <input type="email" class="" name="dmform-1" id="1468593654"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-1" value="Email" id="1397141945"/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput required  small-12 medium-4 large-4  dmRespDesignCol" id="1031046670">
    <label for="dmform-2" id="1139185970">
     Phone:
    </label>
    <input type="tel" class="" name="dmform-2" id="1877606597"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-2" value="Phone" id="1024972058"/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol required" id="1987784782">
    <label for="dmform-4" id="1593551682">
     Business Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="dmform-4" id="1048093637"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-4" value="Business Name:" id="1457409720" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol" id="1693049742">
    <label for="dmform-3" id="1130187566">
     Website (If Applicable):
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="dmform-3" id="1818925844"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-3" value="Website (If Applicable):" id="1910795785" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol required" id="1641134980">
    <label for="dmform-8" id="1128937495">
     Industry:
    </label>
    <select name="dmform-8" id="1322253508">
     <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="" id="1826660918">
     </option>
     <option id="20092">
      Accounting
     </option>
     <option id="40161">
      Administration Services
     </option>
     <option id="43981">
      Advertising / Arts / Media
     </option>
     <option id="20866">
      Banking &amp; Financial Services
     </option>
     <option id="12160">
      Call Centre &amp; Customer Service
     </option>
     <option id="49398">
      Community Services &amp; Development
     </option>
     <option id="4576">
      Constructions
     </option>
     <option id="98548">
      Design &amp; Architecture
     </option>
     <option id="44528">
      Education &amp; Training
     </option>
     <option id="46796">
      Engineering
     </option>
     <option id="18019">
      Farming, Animals &amp; Conservation
     </option>
     <option id="43364">
      Government &amp; Defence
     </option>
     <option id="75015">
      Healthcare &amp; Medical
     </option>
     <option id="84748">
      Hospitality &amp; Tourism
     </option>
     <option id="34677">
      Human Resources &amp; Recruitment
     </option>
     <option id="17487">
      Information &amp; Communication Technology
     </option>
     <option id="59939">
      Insurance &amp; Superannuation
     </option>
     <option id="13704">
      Legal
     </option>
     <option id="62805">
      Manufacturing, Logistics &amp; Transport
     </option>
     <option id="62794">
      Mining, Resources &amp; Energy
     </option>
     <option id="10514">
      Real Estate &amp; Property
     </option>
     <option id="1133">
      Retail &amp; Consumer Products
     </option>
     <option id="94631">
      Sales
     </option>
     <option id="82199">
      Science &amp; Technology
     </option>
     <option id="45914">
      Sports &amp; Recreation
     </option>
     <option id="5262">
      Trades &amp; Services
     </option>
     <option id="34059">
      Other
     </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-8" value="Industry:" id="1319120310" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol required" id="1152789745">
    <label for="dmform-7" id="1886164557">
     Main Form of Marketing:
    </label>
    <select name="dmform-7" id="1596292004">
     <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="" id="1071193801">
     </option>
     <option id="88876">
      Social Media (Organic)
     </option>
     <option id="47157">
      Social Media (Paid)
     </option>
     <option id="35969">
      Google Ads
     </option>
     <option id="35387">
      Website
     </option>
     <option id="16119">
      Business Directory
     </option>
     <option id="35334">
      Print Advertising
     </option>
     <option id="42440">
      Word of Mouth
     </option>
     <option id="27515">
      Email Marketing
     </option>
     <option id="52499">
      Cold Calling
     </option>
     <option id="76102">
      None
     </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-7" value="Main Form of Marketing:" id="1293303285" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 dmRespDesignCol required medium-8 large-8" id="1559730893">
    <label for="dmform-9" id="1112686266">
     What Are Your Marketing Goals? (Eg. # Sales, # Leads)
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="dmform-9" id="1779337920"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-9" value="What Are Your Marketing Goals? (Eg. # Sales, # Leads)" id="1240630133" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 dmRespDesignCol required newLine medium-12 large-12" id="1515955251">
    <label for="dmform-10" id="1387429203">
     What Is Your Biggest Challenge Concerning Marketing?
    </label>
    <textarea name="dmform-10" id="1928030222">
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-10" value="What Is Your Biggest Challenge Concerning Marketing?" id="1924531818" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 dmRespDesignCol newLine required medium-7 large-7" id="1213849291">
    <label for="dmform-5" id="1542410097">
     How Much Are You Currently Spending on Advertisements (Per Month):
    </label>
    <select name="dmform-5" id="1492740570">
     <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="" id="1149567560">
     </option>
     <option id="78017">
      Under $200
     </option>
     <option id="12398">
      Under $500
     </option>
     <option id="54694">
      $500 - $1,000
     </option>
     <option id="48646">
      $1,000 - $1,500
     </option>
     <option id="82243">
      $1,500 - $2,000
     </option>
     <option id="73664">
      $2,000+
     </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-5" value="How Much Are You Currently Spending on Advertisements (Per Month):" id="1584584684" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 dmRespDesignCol required newLine medium-7 large-7" id="1022609856">
    <label for="dmform-6" id="1046499956">
     How Much Do You Have To Spend On A Marketing Consultant (Per Month):
    </label>
    <select name="dmform-6" id="1334491380">
     <option selected="" disabled="" hidden="" value="" id="1737545793">
     </option>
     <option id="81039">
      Max. $500
     </option>
     <option id="11564">
      $500 - $800
     </option>
     <option id="58277">
      $800 - $1,000
     </option>
     <option id="40310">
      $1,000 - $1,200
     </option>
     <option id="44186">
      $1,200 - $1,400
     </option>
     <option id="70088">
      $1,500 - $2,000
     </option>
     <option id="54736">
      $2,000+
     </option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-6" value="How Much Do You Have To Spend On A Marketing Consultant (Per Month):" id="1067191616" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmforminput small-12 medium-4 large-4 dmRespDesignCol newLine" id="1643197675">
    <label for="dmform-11" id="1105984450">
     What Did You Think Of The Workshop Video:
    </label>
    <div class="radiowrapper " id="1925763849">
     <div id="95793" class="contact-checkable-container">
      <input type="radio" value="I found it helpful" name="dmform-11" id="62545" class="checkable-input"/>
      <label for="62545" class="for-checkable" id="1821675904">
       <img alt="" id="24065" class="contact-checkable-img"/>
       <label for="62545" class="custom-contact-checkable" id="1801349237">
       </label>
       <span id="64790">
        I found it helpful
       </span>
      </label>
     </div>
     <div id="73536" class="contact-checkable-container">
      <input type="radio" value="I found it somewhat helpful" name="dmform-11" id="32044" class="checkable-input"/>
      <label for="32044" class="for-checkable" id="1990747670">
       <img alt="" id="75763" class="contact-checkable-img"/>
       <label for="32044" class="custom-contact-checkable" id="1079780755">
       </label>
       <span id="40731">
        I found it somewhat helpful
       </span>
      </label>
     </div>
     <div id="66487" class="contact-checkable-container">
      <input type="radio" value="I did not find it helpful" name="dmform-11" id="62599" class="checkable-input"/>
      <label for="62599" class="for-checkable" id="1469848024">
       <img alt="" id="90856" class="contact-checkable-img"/>
       <label for="62599" class="custom-contact-checkable" id="1263976102">
       </label>
       <span id="17810">
        I did not find it helpful
       </span>
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="label-dmform-11" value="What Did You Think Of The Workshop Video:" id="1019097344" class=""/>
   </div>
   <div class="dmformsubmit dmWidget R" preserve_css="true" id="1636713603">
    <input class="" name="submit" type="submit" value="APPLY" id="1627090743"/>
   </div>
   <input name="dmformsendto" type="hidden" value="info@salespeach.com.au" preserve_css="true" id="1989920116" class=""/>
   <input class="dmActionInput" type="hidden" name="action" value="/_dm/s/rt/widgets/dmform.submit.jsp" id="1374221229"/>
   <input name="dmformsubject" type="hidden" value="Application Form Submission" preserve_css="true" id="1561031043" class=""/>
   <input name="dmformfrom" type="hidden" value="" preserve_css="true" id="1587482394"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="mailChimpIntegrationUUID" value="07a58ffba0fd4b8188688a95b5a6e6d5" [object="" object]="" id="1819829015"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="mailChimpLists" value="2c3824b6a5" [object="" object]="" id="1999233810"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="mailChimp_email" value="dmform-1" class="fieldMapper" id="1500068477"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="mailChimp_firstName" value="dmform-0" class="fieldMapper" id="1413818734"/>
  </form>
 </div>
 <div class="dmform-success" style="display:none" preserve_css="true" id="1480185347" data-success-page="application-successful">
  <p class="rteBlock" no_space_b="true" no_space_e="true">
   Thank you for ccompleting the form.
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="dmform-error" style="display:none" preserve_css="true" id="1772950587">
  <p class="rteBlock" no_space_b="true" no_space_e="true">
   Oops, there was an error submitting your form. Please try again later.
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try anything in JS/ Jquery? if so, please provide it. also add a tag in which scripting language you are working on.

Comment: You can achieve your desired result with Javascript. Get access to the selected drowdown value using `document.getElementById` and accordingly redirect user based on the value using if else statements with `window.location = 'http://based_on_value_link'` inside the statement body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the form action through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-can-i-set-the-form-action-through-javascript)

Comment: Why don't you do it on server-side?

Answer (score -1):

This is JQuery to redirect your page according to selected option

```
$("#1627090743").click(function (){
  if($("#1334491380").attr('id') == "81039") {
     window.location.href= 'https://salespeach.com.au/application-unsuccessful';
  }
  else {
    window.location.href= 'https://salespeach.com.au/application-successful';
  }});
```

I have played with IDs as it should be unique in page.