# How to change form action host dynamically on page?

Tags: javascript

I need to get access to a different server if input field "account" is longer than 10 characters, how can I change the form action target to server2 with JavaScript dynamically?

```html
<form method="get" action="server1/login.php"
    class="get-started-form flex items-center flex-wrap">
  <input name="account" type="text"
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701041/2026606

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the [`keyup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) on the input box to detect whenever the text value changed, then read the value using the [`value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). After that, compare the length and dynamically modify the [`action` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/action) of the `form` element based on your needs.

```js
const getStartedForm = document.querySelector('.get-started-form');
const accountInput = document.querySelector('input[name="account"]');
accountInput.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  if (accountInput.value.length > 10) {
    getStartedForm.action = 'server2/login.php';
  } else {
    getStartedForm.action = 'server1/login.php';
  }
});
```

```html
<form
  method="get"
  action="server1/login.php"
  class="get-started-form flex items-center flex-wrap"
>
  <input name="account" type="text" />
</form>
```