# how to make my button open different .php page

Tags: html

```
<body>
<h1>Home</h1>

<p>Register
Profile:</p>

<form action="profile_submit.php"  method="post" >
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="Register" id="Register" value="Submit"  onclick="submitForm('profile_submit.php')"/>
</p>

<p>Update Profile:</p>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="Update" id="Update" value="update"  onclick="profile_update.php"/>
</p>
```

I want 1 of them to direct to profile_submit.php page while the other to profile_update.php and i know that its not recommended to use 2 action on 1 html form so can you help me with my code?

Comment: Make two forms with different URLs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the form action through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-can-i-set-the-form-action-through-javascript)

Comment: **Actually** (1) you should only show profile_update.php when the user has logged in. (2) you should check whether the same  user credentail (e.g. login email) exists whenever a user registers - reject registration if the same credentail exists (3) you should send an activation email to the registrant with an activation link to activate the account after registration